# Ffmpeg Image overlay with left to right transition

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg, command, overlay

I am using ffmpeg to make a left to right transition for an overlay image, however when I want the image to appear and disappear between specific time intervals it ignores the transition animation and what it does is to only fade in and fade out. Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=rgba,scale=-2:100,fade=in:st=4:d=1.5:alpha=1,fade=out:st=9:d=0.3:alpha=1[png];[0:v][png]overlay=x='min(-1.5*w+6*w*t,0)':3*(H-h)/4-0:shortest=1:enable='between(t,3,10)'" -y output.mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression for `x` in overlay, the time-multiplied operand `6*w*t` is probably increasing so fast that by the time the image fades in, `min` always evaluates to 0.

If you use `x='min(-11*w/3+2*w*t/3,0)'`, it will slide in as it is fading in.

Comment: OMG I have been trying to achieve this for days already! Thanks a lot!